# Azure WebJob deployed from Bitbucket is set up as continuous instead of scheduled

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, azure-webjobs, kudu

When deploying a webjob from Bitbucket (using continuous deployment), the process seems to ignore any settings created for the job, like schedule and name.

The webjob resides in its own solution, without any site.

Is it possible to somehow add a hook or change some variable in the deployment process to deploy the job as scheduled instead of continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about Bitbucket, but more generally about git based deployment. Things are not as smooth as they could be, but can be made to work. One way is:

- Create a dummy Web App in VS. It can empty.
- Add your console app to the same solution, and Add it as a WebJob to the WebApp (details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/)).
- For the scheduling, you may want to look at [this post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/).

Comment: Thanks, works great! Looked like it didn't work at first since the job is marked as "On Demand" in the Azure portal. But I guess this is due to the fact that the schedule is internal / bundled with the job, cause the schedule works as expected.

Comment: Indeed, the portal does not yet know about this new type of schedules. Make sure your site has Always On turned on.